# Rails error after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

After deploying my application online I get this error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

The bundle install worked.
In `development.log` I get only this error:

```
Cache delete: instance
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
127.0.0.1:11211 failed (count: 0)
DalliError: No server available
```

The only reference to `127.0.0.1` is in `development.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1:11211', {..
```

Is this error important or only for cache?

Where else can I look for errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error says that your application can't connect to memcached on `127.0.0.1:11211`.

Make sure you have [installed memcached](http://memcached.org/downloads), and pointed your application to the correct end-point.